# com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1 dosn't contain GoogleSignInOptions class

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

When I try import this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1` and implement this code to get the authentication with google rest API,

```
GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                        .build();
        GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);

        // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
        startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
```

It says `GoogleSignInOptions cannot be resolved to a type` not sure what is missing here,

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post gradle file?

Comment: @akshay_shahane I use it as cordova application. You mean build.gradle file?

Comment: I downloaded as jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-auth/16.0.1 and added in the build path

Comment: @akshay_shahane is it not possible to include them on Cordova applications?